# Как сделать, чтобы изображение не вылазило за div?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать, чтобы изображение-рамка не вылазило за `.container2` и увеличить его (изображние) в ширину на 30 процентов от исходного?
Ссылка на ютуб-запись проблемы:https://youtu.be/wkirG-u8erc
Спасибо!
Код прилагается: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/zy5pqqf1

Comment: Quick Brown Fox, привет. Ты все над этим сайтом трудишься?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй [`border-image`](http://css.yoksel.ru/border-image/), например, так:

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 24.48vh 7.04vh 10.72vh;
  border-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/wky2z.png);
  border-image-slice: 612 176 268;
  border-image-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить для `.container2` CSS стиль `overflow: hidden;`.

На самом деле картинку обрежет любой `overflow`, кроме `visible`.

Вы можете установить `overflow` отдельно по осям с помощью стилей `overflow-x` и `overflow-y`. К примеру: `overflow-x: hidden`.